# Python - How to stop threads from interrupting input?

Tags: python

Whenever a thread prints something, and the user has to input something, the thread interrupts what they are typing and puts it onto a new line.

Example:

```
user: hel
12345
lo world
```

What I want to see is the thread printing before the user input:

```
12345
user: hello world
```

The thread prints at random, so I can't change the time it prints at. I don't want to delay, as the user may not type anything for a long period of time, which would prevent them from seeing the thread's output.

Is there something that I can do?

Comment: If you want a synchronous programs, why are you using threads and printing asynchronously ?

Comment: Redirect the output to main thread and print from there and input from there

Comment: put output lines onto queue. then get them on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

If you do want the thread to stop until it prints, you can use custom print and input functions:

```
lock  = threading.Lock()
def myprint(data):
   lock.acquire()
   print(data)
   lock.release()

def myinput():
   lock.acquire()
   data = input()
   lock.release()
   return data
```

Otherwise I would suggest choosing [sramalingam24's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339021/python-how-to-stop-threads-from-interrupting-input#comment101166668_57339021).

Comment: You forget to wrap also `input` function by lock.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, there is nothing you can do.

Long answer: it depends. There really isn't enough information about your program and the environment you are running on to suggest a suitable solution.

If you are using a Linux distribution or Mac OS, you probably have a terminal that support ncurses.

In this case, you can [use the Python bindings for ncurses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) and some locking to have two or more threads output to different parts of the screen at the same time.

Note, you will likely have to read user input one keystroke at a time, instead of using Pythons `raw_input` or similar to keep your output cleanly arranged on the screen.

And here "output" meas both printing from a thread and "echoing" the user input to the screen (so you really have 2 output sources and not one!)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make it print before user input, what you can do however, is make it wait till its own turn to print something.

This is achieved with synchronization mechanism known as a `Mutex`. It can also be called a `Lock`, which is the case in Python.

Every single time you want to print or get user input, all you have to do is block everything, by aquiring the lock, all other threads will wait for their turn, when you return the lock, only then will they be able to aquire the lock and print.

This should be enough to do what you want:

```py
# sio.py (synchronized io)

import threading

# lock for synchronizing IO, stored globally
# dunders warn user not to touch this stuff
__io_lock = threading.Lock()

# this is questionable, but let's keep it simple
# let's overide default functions with our own and keep old ones
# affects only this module, so it shouldn't be problematic
__print = print
__input = input

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    with __io_lock:
        __print(*args, **kwargs)

def input(*args, **kwargs):
    with __io_lock:
        __input(*args, **kwargs)

# end of sio.py
```

Now you can import and use it.

There's an important thing about it though, while it does not affect Python except for IO, as GIL is present, it will block threads and prevent them from doing anything if they try to print, as they will do absolutely nothing until user enters something and the lock is returned.

To bypass this, you could simply buffer what you want to print, in case lock cannot be aquired, then print it all at once when lock is finally aquired, but that might be messy, and depends on what you really want to do, so I will just provide an example without all that, and you can implement it yourself if you want threads to continue running.

```py
import threading
import time

import sio

def noisy_thread():
    while True:
        # thread will wait till it can print without bothering anyone
        sio.print("noisy_thread: Beep")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = threading.Thread(target=noisy_thread)

    thread.start()

    count = 3
    for i in range(count):
        # input aquires the lock and blocks all other prints/inputs
        sio.input(f"{i+1}/{count}: ") 

    thread.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've chosen to put everything that should be printed into a queue, and then print everything after input. Thanks for your help everyone.